# Integrating both sides of an equation

Tags: calculus, integration

Suppose i have

$g(x)=f(x)$

Now, i integrate both sides of the equation

$\int g(x)dx=\int f(x)dx$

I get:

$G(x)+C=F(x)+C$ , where G(x) and F(x) are anti-derivatives.

because G(x) is the area from 0 to x, as F(x), and because g(x)=f(x), then the 2 constants of integration, to me, must be the same. Is it correct ?

Comment: No. There is no reason why the two constants are the same. The interpretation in terms of areas applies only to definite integrals.

Comment: The area under a curve only applies to the definite integral. You've got indefinite integrals.

Comment: No. You just can't state that in general. However, you can assume w.l.o.g that one of the constants is $0$, i.e. $G(x)=F(x)+C$.

Comment: So the antiderivative F(x) is not the area from 0 to x ?

Comment: No, the antiderivative is a completely different thing.

Comment: @MikeR.: completely different ?

Comment: "Completely" is there for emphasis.

Comment: The antiderivative can be seen as the area… from some $x_0$, not necessarily $0$. For this reason, the two constants can differ.

Comment: @MikeR.: I'd rather emphasize with *slightly* different.

Comment: Well, through the fundamental theorem of calculus, right?

Comment: So, can i say that the antiderivative F(x) is the area of f(x) from a certain point $x_{ a}$  to x, and the antiderivative G(x) is the area of g(x) from a certain point $x_{ b}$ , and $x_{ a}$ not need to be equal to $x_{ b}$  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you say that one function is equal to another function, it means that the result of integration, which is a family of functions that differ only by a constant, of one of the functions will be equal to the result of integration, which is again a family of functions that differ only by a constant, of the other one. That's obviously true because the functions are the same.

Let's say we have two functions $f(x)=x^2+x$ and $g(x)=x(x+1)$. I hope you can see that they are exactly the same function. So, we can write down the following: $f(x)=g(x)$. And we also know that $\int f(x)\,dx=\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^2}{2}+C$. Then, what will $\int g(x)\,dx$ be equal to if we defined $g(x)$ to be equal to $f(x)$? Well, obviously it's going to be the same family of functions: $\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^2}{2}+C$!

$$
\int g(x)\,dx=\int[x(x+1)]\,dx=\int (x^2+x)\,dx=\int f(x)\,dx=\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^2}{2}+C.
$$

The notation $F(x)+C$ just means "a family of functions that differ only by a constant". It's really just a shorthand for this: $\{F(x)+C,C\in\mathbb{R}\}$.

P.S. Don't confuse two different concepts: the definite integral (antiderivative) and the indefinite integral (geometrically, the area under a curve). They're different! There is something that unites them, however, and that something is called the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: So, can i say that the antiderivative F(x) is the area of f(x) from a certain point $x_{ a}$  to x, and the antiderivative G(x) is the area of g(x) from a certain point $x_{ b}$ , and $x_{ a}$ not need to be equal to $x_{ b}$  ?

Comment: You could try and do something like this: $\int_{x_a}^{x}f(t)\,dt=F(t)\bigg|_{x_a}^{x}=F(x)-F(x_a)=F(x)-C_1$ and $\int_{x_b}^{x}g(t)\,dt=G(t)\bigg|_{x_b}^{x}=G(x)-G(x_b)=G(x)-C_2$. But I don't know how you could you use this as a definition of the antiderivative? Those are actually definite integrals. The concept of antiderivative is more closely associated with the indefinite integral. What would you say an antiderivative is in your own words?

Answer (score 2):

Nearly, but as the antiderivatives $F$ and $G$ can themselves differ by a constant, the reasoning can fail.

What you can write is

$$F(x)+C_F=G(x)+C_G$$ and verify the condition at a single point, say

$$F(x_0)+C_F=G(x_0)+C_G,$$ which can be enforced with $$C_G=C_F+F(x_0)-G(x_0).$$

Now it holds for all $x$.

In other words, subtracting both,

$$F(x)-F(x_0)=G(x)-G(x_0)$$

which is equivalent to

$$\int_{x_0}^x f(t)\,dt=\int_{x_0}^x g(t)\,dt.$$

Answer (score 0):

What you're computing is the indefinite integral and there's no reason for the constants of integration to be the same on both the sides. Let $\int f(x) \mathrm dx=F(x)+C_1$ and $\int g(x)\mathrm dx=G(x)+C_2$ In fact you may simply write the following:$$f(x)=g(x) \implies \int f(x)\mathrm dx=\int g(x) \mathrm dx\implies F(x)=G(x)+C \ \text{where} \ C=C_2-C_1$$Note that this is the case even during computation of definite integral, however the effect of the constants of integration gets nullified in the process:$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\mathrm dx=\bigl[F(x)+C_1\bigr]_{a}^{b}=F(b)-F(a)$$

Answer (score 0):

Observe that if $f$ is differentiable on $\Bbb R$ then the derivative of both $f$ and $f+c$ are same which is $f'$ but $f \neq f+c$ unless $c = 0.$